# ArrayStoreException at runtime in JAVA-8 Stream

Tags: exception, java-8, java-stream, autoboxing, arraystoreexception

I have got some issues in below codelines written in java 8

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 3), Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(1, 2));

Integer[][] arr1 = list.stream().map(l ->l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray()).peek((x)->System.out.println(x[0]+","+x[1])).toArray(Integer[][]::new);
```

There is no compilation error at all; But I am getting exception as below.
[image]

Although I am not getting any issue with primitive types but above stream fails with autobox the values. Please help.

Comment: An `int[]` can not be stored in an `Integer[][]`. Either, you change `l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray()` to `l.toArray(new Integer[0])` to get your `Integer[][]`, or you use `int[][] arr1 = list.stream().map(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray()).peek(x -> System.out.println(x[0]+","+x[1])).toArray(int[][]::new);` instead.